Need to run in parallel way with Uni in mutiny
  public void initialize(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
    UniJoin.Builder<Integer> builder = Uni.join().builder();

    Stream.of(1,2,3,4).forEach(r -> {
      builder.add(consultrecord(r));
    });

    Uni<List<Integer>> all = builder.joinAll().usingConcurrencyOf(10).andFailFast();

    System.out.println("FINISH");

  }

  public Uni<Integer> consultrecord (Integer input) {
    try {
      System.out.println("PRUEBA DE TEXT");
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      return Uni.createFrom().failure(e);
    }
    return Uni.createFrom().item(input);
  }



I need to run in parallel way but i see run one to one the 4 four elements  and i need to run all in the same time
how to run uni in parallel way

You might want to check https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/guides/emit-on-vs-run-subscription-on/
Note that here you are starting from an in-memory data source, so the parallelism you might get will be artificial. Remember that Mutiny is a Reactive Streams implementation, so it was made to coordinate the processing of asynchronous I/O sources, not do what java.util.streams does better for in-memory stream processing.
